# Applying Restraints in Octave while Plotting a Graph

Tags: matlab, octave

I am plotting a graph using Octave. I am trying to plot the graph of the following function:

$$y = \ln|\sin x| $$

Where Following Constraints Exist:

$$ 0 \le x \le 22 \land -2 \le y \le 0$$

I know how to draw the graph of basic functions using octave but i am unable to draw appropriate graph for this question. What program should i write to draw graph of above function.

Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically set the values where $y<-2$ to `NaN`, you will get

```
x = linspace(0,22,1000);
y = log(abs(sin(x)));
I = find(y<-2);
y(I) = nan;
plot(x,y)
```

This, however, is not a recommended practice in MATLAB. You can just use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to simply write it as:

```
x = linspace(0,22,1000);
y = log(abs(sin(x)));
figure
plot(x(y>-2),y(y>-2))
```

[image]